# Dymo SDK not printing when told to do so in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dymo

I've been working on a really simple app (or so I thought) to print a label with a simple bar code in it, and some text. I have followed the documentation best I can considering it is vague and rather non-descriptive. 
Here is my code

```
 public void PrintLabel(string serial_num, string part_Num)
    {
        var label = DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Barcode.label");
        label.SetObjectText("Bar_code", serial_num);
        label.SetObjectText("text_box", part_Num);
        label.Print("DYMO LabelWriter 450 Turbo");
    }
```

as you can see this is the simplest way I can do things. 
I've included the `DYMO.Label.Framework` in the standard reference and I have made sure `Barcode.label` is in the base directory and is accessible. When I hit the button which has a method leading to PrintLabel it thinks for a second, and the printer does nothing. There are no jobs in the printer stack qued and I cant see anything weird going on in the output log. (see below).

What Am I doing wrong?

> 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\ProductValidationSoftware.exe'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\DYMO.Label.Framework.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\DYMO.DLS.Runtime.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\DYMO.Common.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\Interop.DYMOBarcodeLib.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols.
>   'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Project
>   Files\ProductValidationSoftware\ProductValidationSoftware\bin\Debug\Interop.DYMOPrintingSupportLib.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols. ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe
>   Information: 0 : Utils.CreateLabelPrintParams(): printParams == null,
>   creating default printParams based on printer type
>   'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Printing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Printing.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ProductValidationSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ReachFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\ReachFramework.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

So the Answer seems to be simple, update the Dymo software on the computer side, and ensure you only include the

using Dymo;

and include only the DymoInterpolerate.dll as the include.

Seems to work fine then.

Not sure why that is?

Comment: How did you manage to find it? I have it running without the `DymoInterpolerate.dll` Adding the reference copies dymo.common.dll dymo.dls.runtime.dll, dymo.label.framework.dll to the bin dir.